# Why are variable value hover tips not showing in functions in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I hover over a variable name in the main code I get a hover tip to display the variables value but this does not appear for function variables. How do I get this to work?

Comment: A variable inside a function is being deleted / released after the execution of that function has completed. Therefore, the variable exists only while execution of that function. If you want to keep the value globally, you have to assign it to a global variable (one that is defined outside the scope of a function).

Comment: Thx - so would you say best practice while I'm testing and fixing would be to declare those variables as global?

Comment: Best practice would probably be to use some kind of logging (e.g. with pythons logging facility, or simple print statements). Defining variables globally can lead to side effects when not done carefully.